# Using a function without returning a value visual basic

Tags: vb.net, function

I'm making a batch development kit in visual basic and i need to be able to call a function that sets textboxes to a saved files text. How do i do this without returning? I tried this, and it lets me run the program, but gives me a warning, not an error. How do i go about doing this? Here is my little function design. P.S. I recently switched back to VB from Java and i'm so used to doing public void. Thanks in advance!

```
    Public Function loadProject()

    End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a `Sub`, which is the equivalent to the Java `void` method.

```
Public Sub LoadProject()

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple answer. :)  Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bad Idea to just have a function that returns a value like a success statement just in case you need it. A call to the function doesn't have to accept or use the return value from the function.

You could even build a class with two values - txtpreviousvalue and txtnewvalue
Have your function return that type and fill an instance of the type with the respective values.

One day, if you need it, you'll have it.
P.S. I'm only posting this as an answer because the good answer posted by sstan is not marked as the answer; You should probably do that.